# Slow render with RTX 3060

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

I'm following the [earth tutorial](https://youtu.be/0YZzHn0iz8U) by Andrew Price.

I'm rendering one single image that is now taking 33 min, and it's only at 9% rendering...
He rendered one image in 14 seconds.

My graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060 which I also ticked in "Preferences" with CUDA. In the render settings, I chose GPU Compute (rendering with Cycles). I'm aware he's using a better GPU, but still, I figured RTX 3060 should be strong enough to render this scene. I have already tried with OptiX, but there's no difference.

By changing the Feature Set from "Experimental" to "Supported" it does render a bit faster. Experimental is chosen in the tutorial to enable Adaptive Subdivision (which I thought should actually speed up render time and not slow it down).

Thank you in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, could you [edit] your question with a screenshot of your render settings?

Comment: Actually _Adaptive Subdivision_ is not making it faster. It is creating displacement (but based on pixel resolution instead of geometry, to put it simple) which has to be computed. If you have displacment on your model relying on _Adaptive Subdivision_ and you switch to _Supported_, then this feature and the displacement is gone, so there's less to compute which makes the render faster. Would you mind showing the other render settings under _Sampling_ as well, like _Noise Threshold_, _Max Samples_ etc.?

Comment: I have updated the post, thank you!

Comment: In addition to Gordon's comment, in the provided screenshot you're using CUDA rendering instead of OptiX, and having both the GPU and CPU selected means you're using Hybrid Rendering, which may or may not be slower.

Comment: I think that just solved the issue. I removed the CPU and switched to OptiX. I thought CUDA was the way to go, thank you so much!

Comment: @FranziskaG Oh, good to know - I didn't actually think of that although it's the same for me, too. I couldn't test it when I wrote my comment, but now back at home I have the same GPU as you have, but a worse CPU. So at home I switch off the CPU because it slows down the render compared to just GPU. At work I have the same CPU as you, but a bad GPU. There I use both and it speeds up the render, so I thought the combination of your CPU and your GPU wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

There're 2 problems of your Cycles rendering devices:

1. In most of cases, don't enable CPU in Cycles rendering devices
2. Use OptiX for NVIDIA GeForce 20/30 series because 20/30 series supports hardware ray tracing. This will accelerate rendering process a lot.

And you should check your render settings. 4096 sampling is not necessary unless there's massive noise when rendering. So you have to set high sampling numbers to save details when denoising.

Comment: "*In most of cases, don't enable CPU in Cycles rendering devices*" Why and do you have data on this?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some problems in your settings. First of all a laptop rtx 3060 is quite slow compared to desktop counter part, and in case of Andrew Price, he uses four 3090s in NVlink.
Next you using hybrid rendering which in most cases slows down the render time.
Also use optix instead of cuda with only gpu selected.
Also use denoiser with optix (not openimagedenoiser) in which case u can higher the noise threshold to 0.2 or something and get a good result.
Bonus, you can check in camera settings render only selected